# haml vs slim

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slim, haml

railsのテンプレートエンジンの選定を記述量とパフォーマンスで選定したいと考えています。
有名どころだと haml, slimが良いかなと思っているのですが、特にパフォーマンスに関して両者に相違はありますか？

https://github.com/haml/haml
https://github.com/slimphp/Slim

## 追記

解決したため回答を追加しました。
https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/34571/22531

Comment: 2017/05/09日現在、star数ではslimの方が上です。（haml: 3146, slim: 7950）

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[hamlit](https://github.com/k0kubun/hamlit)にパフォーマンステストの結果が記載されています。
その結果によると `haml` と `hamlit` を同時に使用するのがもっともパフォーマンスが高いようです。